# Eclipse, MinGW подключение lib

Tags: eclipse, lib

Добрый день, нужно подключить библиотеку "libwsock32.a", прописал в eclipse в project/properties/minGW C++ Linker/libraries libwsock32.a, eclipse руганулся

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -llibwsock32.a
```

Вижу, что libwsock32.a лежит в C:\MinGW\lib\ , прописываю в project/properties/minGW C++ Linker/libraries -path "C:\MinGW\lib\" , получаю точно такую же ошибку, что не находит файл, подскажите пожалуйста, что я сделал неправильно, спасибо за внимание.

Comment: прописал полный путь в к библиотеке, теперь пишет так:

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lC:\MinGW\lib\libwsock32.a

Comment: @fortunado, если честно, то про Eclipse не знаю. "Напрямую" в винде я в командной строке (или Makefile) пишу так

     gcc txmsg.c -o txmsg -lws2_32 -lwsock32

и оно собирается.

Comment: спасибо, но хотелось бы узнать, почему у меня с eclipse не получается.

Answer (score 1):

ага, разобрался), в общем если хочешь добавить libwsock32.a , то нужно прописать только wsock32, остальное eclipse по ходу добавляет сам.